# Fields where for some $n$ all polynomials of degree $n$ are reducible but a degree $n+1$ irreducible exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

**True or false**: there exists a field $K$ and a positive integer $n$ such that every polynomial over $K$ of degree $n$ is reducible (in $K[z]$) but there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $n+1$.

**Motivation**: two extreme cases are well known.  If $K={\mathbb Q}$ the statement is false as there are irreducible polynomials of every degree.  I am not sure but I believe this is also true for finite fields.  If $K={\mathbb R}$ then there are irreducible polynomials of degree $1$ and $2$ only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bigcup_{m\ge 1}\Bbb{F}_{p^{2^m}}$ doesn't have any quadratic extension.

The quadratic closure of $\Bbb{Q}$ works too: that is $E=\bigcup_{m\ge 0} E_m$ where $E_0=\Bbb{Q},E_{m+1}=E_m(\{ a^{1/2},a\in E_m\})$. Any element $b\in E$ is contained in a finite tower of quadratic extensions so $[\Bbb{Q}(b):\Bbb{Q}]$ divides a power of $2$, therefore $x^3-2$ is irreducible over $E$.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm not great on field theory so I may well have misunderstood, but is there a typo near the end?  It seems to me that every element has degree a power of $2$, so there are no elements of degree $3$, so $x^3-2$, and in fact any cubic, must be reducible, not irreducible as you wrote.

Comment: If $x^3-2$ is reducible then it has a root $b$ in $E$ so $3=[\Bbb{Q}(b):\Bbb{Q}]$ divides a power of $2$ which is absurd. On the other hand by construction every quadratic polynomial $\in E[x]$ is reducible. @David

Comment: Thanks, got it now.  I was getting mixed up between an element of $\mathbb C$ having degree $3$ over $E$ (which is possible) and an element of $E$ having degree $3$ over $\mathbb Q$ (which is not).